# php - check multiple date ranges for gaps within wider range

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an online membership system where we are required by local law enforcement to provide 5 year address histories for all members. Within this 5 years there are allowed to be overlaps, but there may not be any gaps. Members enter their addresses, stored in a mysql database with the address and a from & to date for each address. The data is input by the member as a month and year. This is stored as the first of the month for the 'from' date and the last of the month for the 'to' date.

I have my $array which is compiled from a mysqli query of the database for a particular member to pull all of the date ranges for the address they have provided. This array populates nicely with my loop to make.

```
$array[] = array("from"=>$row['date_from'],"to"=>$row['date_to']);
```

I have tried converting each of these ranges to a number of days length and adding them all but where addresses overlap (allowed & necessary) it can be more than 5 years even when there are gaps in the address history.

All I need is for $complete to be TRUE or FALSE, I dont need the number of days gap.

Open to doing it as a mysql query or php.

Im sorry for not providing a half-working code -  my only idea is to loop through 1825 days (5 years) to see if each one is represented.

Comment: If you want a solution in SQL, then you should provide more information about the structure of the table where the data comes from -- sample data is always helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can see how that would have been helpful... Sorry it was 2am!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive function will go through your array of ranges, combining the ones that overlap until they've been combined as much as possible. If the result is more than one range, you've got a gap. I've also used a helper function to make finding overlaps cleaner/easier, and I'm assuming your dates look like `'Y-m-d'`.

```
<?php

// First, here's how to use it. If we can't combine all the ranges, and the 
// final combined range doesn't reach back 5 years or to the present,
// we have a gap.
$mergedRanges = combineRanges($myArray);
if (count($mergedRanges) > 1
    || $mergedRanges[0]['from'] > date('Y-m-d', time() - 157680000) // 5 years ago
    || $mergedRanges[0]['to'] < date('Y-m-d')) // present
    echo 'Gaps found';

/**
 * Recursive function to combine ranges.
 *
 * @param array $ranges
 * @return array Array of combined ranges (has only 1 element if no gaps)
 */
function combineRanges(array $ranges)
{
    $mergedRanges = array();
    $usedKeys = array();

    // Nested foreach compares each unique pair of ranges for overlap.
    // If the a range has already been accounted for, it can be skipped.
    foreach ($ranges as $k1 => $range1) {
        if (!in_array($k1, $usedKeys)) {
            foreach ($ranges as $k2 => $range2) {
                if (!in_array($k1, $usedKeys) && $k1 > $k2) {

                    // If ranges overlap, combine them and make a note that
                    // they've already been included
                    if (rangesOverlap($range1, $range2)) {
                        $newRange = array(
                            'from' => min($range1['from'], $range2['from']),
                            'to' => max($range1['to'], $range2['to'])
                        );
                        // It's possible the resulting range could already
                        // be accounted for by a different combo of ranges,
                        // so check first
                        if (!in_array($newRange, $mergedRanges))
                            $mergedRanges[] = $newRange;
                        $usedKeys[] = $k1;
                        $usedKeys[] = $k2;

                    // Otherwise, add the 2nd range to $mergedRanges
                    } elseif (!in_array($k2, $usedKeys)) {
                        $mergedRanges[] = $range2;
                        $usedKeys[] = $k2;
                    }

                    // If $range1 didn't have any overlaps, add it here
                    if (!in_array($k1, $usedKeys)) {
                        $mergedRanges[] = $range1;
                        $usedKeys[] = $k1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If $ranges and $mergedRanges have the same # of elements,
    // or if $ranges only had 1 element to begin with,
    // that means we couldn't merge any more. Otherwise, recurse!
    if (count($ranges) == 1)
        return $ranges;
    return count($mergedRanges) == 1 || (count($ranges) == count($mergedRanges))
        ? $mergedRanges
        : combineRanges($mergedRanges);
}

/**
 * Helper function to see if 2 ranges overlap.
 *
 * @param array $range1
 * @param array $range2
 * @return boolean
 */
function rangesOverlap(array $range1, array $range2)
{
    // Find the day before each range in order to combine ranges
    // that don't overlap but are right next to each other.
    $overlap = false;
    $range1Before = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($range1['from'])));
    $range2Before = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($range2['from'])));

    // Account for when $range1 is first or when $range 2 is first
    if ($range1['from'] <= $range2['from'] && $range1['to'] >= $range2Before
        || $range2['from'] <= $range1['from'] && $range2['to'] >= $range1Before)
       $overlap = true;

    return $overlap;
}
```

Comment: finding this difficult to successfully implement, I have the functions in a separate page which I am calling with require_once, and the first part after the call in the main page. 
For testing purposes the array that it's being fed is currently `Array  (  
[0] => Array ( [from] => 2008-06-30 [to] => 2015-01-06 )
 )`

Comment: Sorry, the function didn't account for when the initial input has only 1 element, like your test case there. Please see the extra `return` condition I added just above the final `return` in `combineRanges()`

Comment: @SLV having any luck?